# Http2 Client and Server Implementation

Tags: java, jetty, http2, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am looking for sample examples implementing all the features of HTTP/2(Client-Server) like STREAMS,FRAMES PUSH_PROMISE,HPACK with detailed configuration of each so that it can be tweaked for performance using JETTY EMBEDDED(9.4.32 or 10.X).

I could find one here https://github.com/fstab/http2-examples but its very old version implementation. Can anyone help me with the reference ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples of how to use the Jetty HTTP/2 low-level APIs in the updated documentation for Jetty 10.

The HTTP/2 client library APIs are described in [this section](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/10.0.0-SNAPSHOT/programming-guide/index.html#pg-client-http2).

The HTTP/2 server library APIs are described in [this section](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/10.0.0-SNAPSHOT/programming-guide/index.html#pg-server-http2).

You can find other examples in the Jetty tests for HTTP/2, see for example in [this directory](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-10.0.x/jetty-http2/http2-client/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http2/client).

"Tweaking for performance" HTTP/2 is an advanced task, and I recommend that you start with the default Jetty settings before adventuring in changing them -- most of the times the performance is already good enough.

Feel free to contact the Jetty Project by [opening an issue](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues) to discuss HTTP/2 performance.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick response :).I accept your recommendation and I will go through the above reference first.